# Need to create a new array from old one with some changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array:

```
let oldarr = [{typeid:1,percent:50,key:1, name:"ger"},
              {typeid:3,percent:50,key:2, name:"geghr"},
              {{typeid:5,percent:50,key:3, name:"ggdfer"}]
```

I want to create a new one that looks like this:

```
let newarr = [{id:'', percent:''}]
```

The `newarr`'s `id` is equal to `typeid` of `oldarr`. How to create new array?

Comment: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using the map function:

```js
let oldarr = [{typeid:1,percent:50,key:1, name:"ger"},
              {typeid:3,percent:50,key:2, name:"geghr"},
              {typeid:5,percent:50,key:3, name:"ggdfer"}];

let newArray = oldarr.map(item=> ({id : item.typeid, percent: item.percent}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let oldarr = [{typeid:1,percent:50,key:1, name:"ger"},
              {typeid:3,percent:50,key:2, name:"geghr"},
              {typeid:5,percent:50,key:3, name:"ggdfer"}]
              
let newarr=oldarr.map((e)=>{
   let {typeid,...rest}=e;
    return {
    ...rest,
    id:typeid
}
})

console.log(newarr); // your final custom array
```